# What does the first argument do in toast.setGravity

Tags: android, android-toast

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Toast!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT); 
toast.setGravity(Gravity.AXIS_PULL_AFTER , 0, 0); toast.show();
```

what is the role of Gravity.AXIS_PULL_AFTER argument in order to positiong the `Toast` on the UI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#makeText(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20int)):

> Make a standard toast that just contains a text view.
>
> Context: The context to use. Usually your Application or **Activity**
>   object.

Generally, **this** will be a reference to the activity calling Toast. However, if you are inside an anonymous class (for example, creating a click listener for a button), you will lose reference to your activity.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter `this` is the object which tells the `Toast` where to show it, in your case is `this` your `Activity` which extends a `Context`. Note that `this` is used a lot around Android widgets. If you are using `this` inside an anonymous class e.g. an `onClickListener()`, use `YourActivityName.this` instead.

Answer (score 0):

There is no clear specification for it according to Google documentation. 
Its just a parameter that tells the current activity or application where makeToast function has to show Toast message.  current activity or application